# PySpark ordering within partition not working properly

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm currently trying to sort a large amount of data and write it to json line objects with PySpark (underlying storage mechanisme is S3 and I use AWS glue for triggering the code). I have the following code:

```
dataframe_with_year_month_columns
.orderBy("field1","field2").write.format("json")
.partitionBy("year","month").mode("overwrite").save(v_target_path)
```

When I check the output some of it is ordered properly like this:

```
{"field1", "field2", "value", "value", "value"}
{"field1", "field2", "value", "value", "value"}
{"field1", "field2", "value", "value", "value"}
{"field1", "field2", "value", "value", "value"}
```

However, some parts are not properly sorted:

```
{"field1", "field2", "value", "value", "value"}
{"field2", "field1", "value", "value", "value"}
{"field1", "field2", "value", "value", "value"}
{"field2", "field1", "value", "value", "value"}
```

How can I make sure that within a partition (records in same year and month) are properly sorted? It is isn't necessary to sort the records over the entire dataset, just within year and month.

Comment: Did you try `sortWithinPartitions` ? (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=pivot#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.sortWithinPartitions)

Comment: @A.Görünücü Yes, before I tried `sortWithinPartitions` and that method also doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Could you include the steps you take to check the order?

Comment: @user10938362 The output of this query are json line objects. I took a few from S3 bucket in which it is written and saw that the last couple files are sorted while the others are not